# How to use LIKE operator in PHP to get data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from 'MySql' where the $path value matches any value to the database using PHP but the query crach when I use LIKE with '%%' but when I use LIKE without percentage '%%' it works.

I have try this query directly to MySQL Workbench and it works perfect.

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

```
$sourceType = 'object';
$sourceId = 189;
$path = 'test'; //int or string value

SELECT d.targetid as id, d.sourcetype as type, CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) as path
FROM dependencies d
INNER JOIN objects o ON o.o_id = d.targetid AND d.targettype= 'object'
WHERE d.sourcetype = '" . $sourceType. "' AND d.sourceid = " . $sourceId . " AND CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) LIKE CONCAT('%', $path, '%');
```

I have tried in this way bat also doesn't work: `LIKE '%" . $path . "%';`

Only when I use: `REGEXP '".$path."'` it works but it have problems with case sensitive value and sometime doesn't pull all the data. If there are 4 rows that include 'test' it gets only 3 rows for example.

Comment: You should look at Prepared Statements instead of concatenating strings into your queries like that. Add the % symbols when you pass the `$path` value as a parameter. Maybe the issue is quote-related, which a Prepared Statement would fix for you.

Comment: _"but the query crach"_ — Does that mean you get an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: @droopsnoot the query that executed is like this  `WHERE d.sourcetype = 'object' AND d.sourceid = 189 AND CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) LIKE '%test%'`

Comment: @rickdenhaan I'm using this in [Pimcore](https://pimcore.com) and it say just 'uncaught error'

Comment: Check this site: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing well.
I have reviewed your code and reorganized it a bit to try to solve the problem you were having. You can try it out and let me know if it works for you.

```
<?php
$sourceType = 'object';
$sourceId = 189;
$path = 'test'; //int or string value

$query = "SELECT 
    d.targetid as id,
    d.sourcetype as type,
    CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) as path
FROM dependencies d
    INNER JOIN objects o 
        ON o.o_id = d.targetid AND d.targettype= 'object'
WHERE 
    d.sourcetype = '$sourceType' AND 
    d.sourceid = '$sourceId' AND 
    CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) LIKE '%$path%'
";
```

Comment: Hi Gilberth Monge thank you for your answer, but Unfortunately it doesn't work and the error message is: 'Uncaught Error'.

Comment: If I generate the query with the code you provided, it generates the following query. Could you verify if it's the same one that generates for you?

SELECT  d.targetid as id, d.sourcetype as type, CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) as path FROM dependencies d INNER JOIN objects o  ON o.o_id = d.targetid AND d.targettype= 'object' WHERE  d.sourcetype = 'object' AND  d.sourceid = '189' AND  CONCAT(o.o_path, o.o_key) LIKE '%test%'

Comment: Yes, it's the same for me, I don't know why it's not working because I test the query in Workbench and it returns the data. Maybe this is a Pimcore thing that doesn't allow it.

Comment: I think the same. They must be security measures.